# Web.config entry to connect to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-config, database-connection, connection-string

Well I'm trying to change the connection of my application from Oracle to SQL Server. I have this in web.config.

```
<compilation debug="true">
    <assemblies>
        ...
        <add assembly="System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        ...
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

and

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DatabaseProvider" value="Test.App.Oracle8i"/>
    <add key="SmtpUser" value="mail@example.com"/>
    <add key="SmtpPassword" value="testpassword"/>
    <add key="SmtpDefaultSender" value="mail@example.com"/>
    <add key="SmtpHost" value="mail.example.com"/>
    <add key="SmtpPort" value="25"/>
    <add key="EnableSsl" value="False"/>
</appSettings>
```

and this

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CnString" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=loCALHOST)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));User Id=TESTUSER;Password=TESTPASSWORD;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

When I change these values ​​for these application will not run and mark errors.

```
<compilation debug="true">
    <assemblies>
        ...
        <add assembly="System.Data.SqlClient, Version=10.50.1600, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        ...
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

and

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DatabaseProvider" value="Test.App.SqlServer"/>
    <add key="SmtpUser" value="mail@example.com"/>
    <add key="SmtpPassword" value="testpassword"/>
    <add key="SmtpDefaultSender" value="mail@example.com"/>
    <add key="SmtpHost" value="mail.example.com"/>
    <add key="SmtpPort" value="25"/>
    <add key="EnableSsl" value="False"/>
</appSettings>
```

and the last

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CnString" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MSSQLSERVER)));Initial Catalog=TESTDATABASE;User Id=TESTUSER;Password=TESTPASSWORD;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

or

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CnString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=TESTDATABASE;User Id=TESTUSER;Password=TESTPASSWORD;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I do not understand is supposed to make the lines.

```
<add assembly="System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add key="DatabaseProvider" value="Test.App.Oracle8i"/>
<add name="CnString" connectionString="Data Source=**(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=loCALHOST)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)))**;User Id=TESTUSER;Password=TESTPASSWORD;"/>
```

Comment: For SQL Server - you just need to <ConnectionStrings> section and use it in the code using ConfigurationManager class.. Rest all you can remove which you have for Oracle.. There is not a 1 to 1 mapping as every provider need different settings.

Comment: Well I'm new to this and do not quite understand what you say. Could you give an example? Or you could tell me the steps to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The only 2 lines you need to connect to SQL Server is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CnString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=TESTDATABASE;User Id=TESTUSER;Password=TESTPASSWORD;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</assemblies>
```

(change version and publicKeyToken in case of .NET 2.0/3.x)

Then use:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("CnString");
// ...
```

That's it.

---

In .NET there is no such assembly as `System.Data.SqlClient, Version=10.50.1600, ...`. SqlClient is the part of standart .NET Framework distribution.

For example, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx):

```
Namespace:  System.Data.SqlClient
Assembly:  System.Data (in System.Data.dll)
```